# Building a striking alarm. How can a solenoid driving circuit activate every 3 seconds?

Tags: circuit-design

I want to build a mechanism that physically hits something (in my case a small gong) a few times at a given time (alarm time.)

I have a digital timer as the ON/OFF control and a 12V solenoid attached to a basic solenoid driving circuit as shown below:

[image: Solenoid Driving Circuit]

*(source: https://theorycircuit.com/solenoid-driver-circuit/)*

Because I'm trying to build an alarm gong, I'd like the solenoid to hit the gong every 3 seconds once the digital timer has switched ON. Is there an easy solution to implement this aspect of the circuit? I wouldn't want to use an Arduino.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to make up a whole project for you? We don't crowdsource project ideas from scratch. Vote close because "needs more details or clarity". Please, show us what exactly you want (hitting a church bell vs hitting a tea cup with a pin) and **what ideas you already have** and what requirements for the device you have (what microcontrollers you can use, if any, how expensive can the parts be, precision requirements etc., the more info the better), and we will probably point you in the right direction from there. Please, fix your question. Thank you.

Comment: So ... you want to build a [Doorbell like this](https://home.howstuffworks.com/home-improvement/repair/doorbell3.htm)?

Comment: @sime please provide a source to the image of where it came from

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [spring-loaded solenoid](https://hackaday.com/2018/05/23/mechanisms-solenoids/) for this, with its plunger hitting your gong (or whatever.)

Keep in mind that solenoids are inductive loads, so be sure to add an antiparallel diode across the solenoid to ensure that you won't blow up whatever will be driving that solenoid due to "inductive kickback". If you are going to drive it by a microcontroller, be sure to use some NPN transistor with a suitable base resistor to actually drive the solenoid, as driving it directly from microcontroller IO pins will certainly exceed the rated IO pin currents and damage your IO. Do look up solenoid driving circuits for more info.

I'd also suggest checking out the [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) for similar kinds of questions. (EE SE is more for purely electronics-related stuff, Arduino sounds like anything DIY electro-mechanical)